# Rabbitmq MQTT Bad username or bad password

Tags: rabbitmq, mqtt

I installed Rabbit MQ on my Ubuntu 16.04 Server. After that, I enabled plugins for MQTT for RabbitMQ. In `rabbitmq-plugins list` I can see that MQTT plugin is enabled and running on the server.

I then added the following configuration file for MQTT at this location

```
/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config
```

and restarted the server:

```
[{rabbit,        [{tcp_listeners,    [5672]}]},
 {rabbitmq_mqtt, [{default_user,     <<"myuser">>},
              {default_pass,     <<"mypass">>},
              {allow_anonymous,  false},
              {vhost,            <<"/">>},
              {exchange,         <<"amq.topic">>},
              {subscription_ttl, 1800000},
              {prefetch,         10},
              {ssl_listeners,    []},
              %% Default MQTT with TLS port is 8883
              %% {ssl_listeners,    [8883]}
              {tcp_listeners,    [1883]},
              {tcp_listen_options, [{backlog,   128},
                                    {nodelay,   true}]}]}
].
```

Now When I am trying to publish a message to rabbitmq server like:

```
import paho.mqtt.publish as publish
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

publish.single('/',
  payload='hello world',
  hostname='xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', # My servers IP address
  auth={'username':'myuser', 'password':'mypass'},
  port=1883,
protocol=mqtt.MQTTv311)
```

It gives me this error:

> paho.mqtt.MQTTException: Connection Refused: bad user name or password.

There is no Encryption for now. So what am I doing wrong?

I tried the same procedure with Mosquitto MQTT Broker and it worked fine. I think the issue is with my rabbitmq configuration.

Comment: does your user have access to virtualhost / ?

Comment: I dont know Its my first time with rabbitmq so I dont know that

Comment: I would recommend to install this admin plugin and check there the permissions https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html

Comment: I already has instaled this and enabled. When I am going to following address `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5672` The page is not working

Comment: Sorry It was on port 15672.. My bad

Comment: I could not access the page. I think there was some issue with my user config so I deleted the user and recreated it. Now it is working fine.

Comment: glad it did work out.